# Calling two over loaded web method by jquery in asp.net(web form) page

Tags: jquery, webforms, webmethod

i have two method having same with attribute called `[WebMethod]` but one take parameter and one is parameter less.when i am trying to call parameter less page method by jquery then error occur.i like to know overloading of web method in asp.net webform page is not possible. if possible where i am making the mistake.

### here is my sample code

my two web method defined in aspx code behind page

```
        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetFaxUI()
        {
            string outputToReturn = "";
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Page pageHolder = new Page();

            BBAReman.UserControls.ucFax ctl = (BBAReman.UserControls.ucFax)pageHolder.LoadControl("~/UserControls/ucFax.ascx");
            HtmlForm tempForm = new HtmlForm();
            tempForm.Controls.Add(ctl);
            pageHolder.Controls.Add(tempForm);
            StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, output, false);
            outputToReturn = output.ToString();
            return outputToReturn;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetFaxUI(string Country)
        {
            string outputToReturn = "";
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Page pageHolder = new Page();

            BBAReman.UserControls.ucFax ctl = (BBAReman.UserControls.ucFax)pageHolder.LoadControl("~/UserControls/ucFax.ascx");
            ctl.LocalizeUI(Country);
            HtmlForm tempForm = new HtmlForm();
            tempForm.Controls.Add(ctl);
            pageHolder.Controls.Add(tempForm);
            StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, output, false);
            outputToReturn = output.ToString();
            return outputToReturn;
        }
```

### here is the way i am calling web method by jquery

```
 jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "FaxUI.aspx/GetFaxUI",
            data: {},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                sHtml = data.d;
                sHtml = $(sHtml).find('#content').html();
                $sHtml = $(sHtml)
                $sHtml.css({ 'display': 'none' }).appendTo('div#dialog');
                $.doTimeout(1000, function () {
                    $(".ui-dialog").animate({
                        left: (($(window).width() - 346) / 2) + 'px',
                        top: (($(window).height() - 305) / 2) + 'px',
                        height: '305px', width: '346px'
                    }, 200,
                    function () {
                        $("#dialog").removeClass("BusyStyles").find('#faxmain').fadeIn(2000);
                        $("#dialog").css({ height: '26px' });
                    });
                });
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
```

before the same code was working but the moment i over load the method `GetFaxUI()` then i am getting error. please guide me what i am making mistake. thanks

Comment: You can't overload web methods.  You'll need to give them different names instead.  I'd also recommend you make 1 private function to do the work, which is called by both your web methods, rather than duplicating all the code and just adding 1 line.

Comment: is there no way to overload the web method by using any attribute.

Comment: No there isn't.  You just need 2 methods with unique names.  Why not simply call the 2nd method `GetFaxUIByCountry`?